# How can I get all the XSD validation errors from an XML file in dotnet?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd

Caveat: I'm fairly new to .NET so I'm unfamiliar with a lot of libraries available.

I have developed a function app using java that I'm having to port over to C#.  I am currently using the built in XSD validation library for .NET and my file *is* being successfully validated, however when testing the results against the java version there are significantly less validation errors being reported in the .NET version.

**Root XSD file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="schema_namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="schema_namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="included_xsd_1.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="included_xsd_2.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="included_xsd_3.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="included_xsd_4.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="included_xsd_5.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="DEMDataSet">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Root Tag</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dCustomElement" type="dCustomElement" id="dElementSection" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Contains information for custom elements.</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Report" id="ReportGroup" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Container Tag to hold each instance of a record</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="from_included_xsd_1" type="type" id="typeSection">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Some Information</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="from_included_2" type="type" id="typeSection" minOccurs="0">
                                <xs:annotation>
                                    <xs:documentation>Some Information</xs:documentation>
                                </xs:annotation>
                            </xs:element>
                            
                            ...
                            
                            
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="timeStamp" type="DateTimeType" use="required"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My issue appears to be occuring when there is a missing element in one of my included xsd files, when this happens all subsequent errors in that xsd file are not reported (e.g. if the initial element is missing, no other validation errors are reported for that xsd file and the validation moves on to the next included xsd).

My code is pretty much lifted straight from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset):

```
    public XsdValidationResult ValidateXml(string filePath)
    {
        var schemas = GetSchemas();
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.Schemas.Add(schemas);
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
        settings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += XsdValidationEventHandler;

        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath, settings);
        var doc = new XmlDocument
        {
            PreserveWhitespace = true
        };
        doc.Load(reader);
        return GetValidationResult();
    }

    private void XsdValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Severity != XmlSeverityType.Error) return;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(e.Message);
        sb.Append($" Line Number: {e.Exception.LineNumber}");
        sb.Append($" Position: {e.Exception.LinePosition}");
        _errors.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
```

The validation error I get looks something like this (before moving on to the next schema):

> The element 'subSchema.elementGroup' in namespace 'namespace' has
> invalid child element 'subSchema.element02' in namespace 'namespace'.
> List of possible elements expected: 'subSchema.element03' in namespace
> 'namespace'.

I did come across this possible explanation of what is happening in the Microsoft docs:

> When the new XmlReader has been closed, the original XmlReader will be
> positioned on the EndElement node of the sub-tree. Thus, if you called
> the ReadSubtree method on the start tag of the book element, after the
> sub-tree has been read and the new XmlReader has been closed, the
> original XmlReader is positioned on the end tag of the book element.

but this behaviour is different from what I need :(

Ultimately my question is, is there a way to continue parsing the XML file after an element has been discovered as missing (either using a different library or through the included .NET library) so as to capture all XSD validation errors?

Comment: It is never a good idea to post incomplete samples. I don't see anything wrong with your .NET code, I would, however, also suggest to output warnings (unless you already did that and saw they don't convey information for your use case). I don't see any relation between the "possible explanation" and your code as it doesn't use `ReadSubtree`. As for other libraries in the .NET world, in the commercial world both Saxon EE and Altova are usable from .NET and do support XSD 1.1.

Comment: What are the actual XML and XSD files and what do you expect? What's your *actual* code? `ReadSubtree` isn't mentioned or used in the article you link to or the code you posted. The article does say you can use XDocument and LINQ-to-XML to load an entire document and then validate it. The article you linked to shows how to enable validation when loading an XmlDocument, not how to find errors in that document. If the document isn't valid, it isn't valid and there's no reason to keep loading it.

Comment: You can load an XmlDocument first, and *then* use [Validate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmldocument-validate(system-xml-schema-validationeventhandler)). The article you linked to though shows how to [use XDocument instead of the old XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/validate-xsd) class to load and validate.

Comment: Finally, XmlReader is a fast-forward reader meant for reading elements one by one, in a loop. Your code uses XmlDocument, not XmlReader, and XmlDocument.Load has no reason to keep loading an invalid doc. You can use XmlReader directly to read elements . You may be able to use, eg `while (reader.read());` to read the entire file and get more errors

Comment: Note that a validator has to make some pragmatic decisions about how to continue after finding the first error. There's no perfect way of deciding whether a subsequent error is independent, or merely a consequence of the first. Two different validators will quite legitimately make different decisions and therefore report different numbers of errors.

Comment: Is that .NET framework or .NET core? For .NET framework, you could also try to IKVM compile the Xerces Java parser to C#/.NET and run it with .NET.

Comment: Warning may be disabled in the XML Reader.  Use XmlReadSettings to report warnings :  settings.ValidationFlags = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;